# Log last commit message to application log after git pull

Tags: git

My deployment process for a website consists of a simple `git pull` on the branch I'm deploying.  I'd like to append to my application (custom) log file whenever I execute a `git pull`.  Preferably I'd append the last commit message & hash.  This will be useful to understand what version of the codebase was in production to add context to all the other things (errors, warnings, info etc) I am logging to this file.

It doesn't look like git has a "post pull" hook - has anyone accomplished this?  `post-merge` doesn't seem to run when the pull is a simple fast-forward.

Comment: You're right that git doesn't have a post-pull hook.  You could create an alias like `git deploy` that does a pull and then runs another command to do your logging.

Answer (score 0):

I took @dan's advice and make a git alias `deploy` in my .git/config file:

```
[alias]
    deploy = "! git pull && ./post-pull.sh"
```

The script file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n-----------GIT PULL-------------\n" >> storage/logs/laravel.log
git log -1 --oneline >> storage/logs/laravel.log
echo -e "\n-----------GIT PULL-------------\n" >> storage/logs/laravel.log
```